# What is the time complexity of the following code fragment?

Tags: time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the following code fragment?
We have 3 nested loops.

```
void function(int n)
{
int i, j,k, count 0;

for (i= n / 3; i <= n; i++)

    for (j =1; j <= n/2; j= 2 *j)

        for (k= 1; k*k<= n; k++)

             count ++;
}
```

Comment: Try running with sample values of n, start going up in steps of 50 and then plot the result agiast the value of count at the end of the function.   Use excel for doing the plotting, just output n, count with a tab separating them, each run on a new line, then you can copy+paist into excel.

Answer (score 1):

You should do your homework yourself. Reading my answer will teach you nothing.

1st loop :  O (n*2/3)
2nd loop : O (log2 (n/2))
3rd loop :  O (sqrt(n))

total : O (n*2/3 * log2(n/2) * sqrt(n))

Proof:

```
<?php
function x ($n)
{
    $count=0;

    for ($i= $n / 3; $i <= $n; $i++)
        for ($j =1; $j <= $n/2; $j= 2 *$j)
            for ($k= 1; $k*$k<= $n; $k++)
                 $count ++;
    return $count;
}

$base = 10;
for ($i = 0 ; $i != 4 ; $i++)
{
    $x = x($base);
    $y = 2*$base/3 * log($base/2,2) * sqrt($base);
    $ratio = $x/$y;
    printf ("%-4d $ratio<br>", $base);
    $base *= 10;
}
?>
```

output:

```
   10 1.2870133211442
  100 1.0684184354174
 1000 0.9845391957853
10000 1.0580203701412
```

Answer (score 0):

Formally (Sigma notation) and empirically, this is the exact solution for your algorithm:

[image]